# Images not being displyed gmail html signature

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, signature

I created a basic signature using HTML Tables that contains some images. I have inserted the images using `<img>` Tags. The images are hosted on a remote server.

After making the signature in HTML, to insert the signature on Gmail. I followed the following procedure:

1. open the HTML file, copy the content using 'ctrl+a' / 'ctrl+c'
2. open gmail -> settings -> signatures -> add new signature and paste 'ctrl+v' on the editor.

Everything works fine. The HTML structure and the inline styles stay intact. However, the images do not load up. Instead, I get a broken image icon instead of images, which you get when the image is not found. When I try to compose the signature, I see my signature without the image on the Gmail email compose editor.

When I send the email, however, everything works perfectly fine, the image on the signature loads up perfectly when I open the email in the inbox or on the sent item.

My issue is I want the images on my signature to load up when I am composing the email as well. The only solution I find on the internet is to turn on the plain text mode while composing the email. Turning off/on plain text mode does not work for me.

Comment: Could you put the code here?

Comment: Hi, The code is plain HTML, nothing special. and the img tag with scr=" some remote location." the image is being loaded correctly when you open it on a web browser.